# How to position certain elements in the navbar on the right

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a navbar for a website and wanted to have 4 elements on the left side of the screen and 2 on the right side of the screen. I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I'm just not getting the elements to float left and right.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <!--<li><a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="../img/PowerUpLogo.gif" class="logo"></a></li>-->
            <li><a href="home.html">Brand</a></li>
            <li><a href="stories.html">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="community.html">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Link</a></li>
            <span class="padding"><a href="log_in.html" class="button button-log-in">Log In</a></span>
            <span class="padding"><a href="sign_up.html" class="button button-sign-up">Sign Up</a></span>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
/*****NAVBAR****/
#navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.5% 2%;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    color: #4F8E64;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/**********************
******NAV BUTTONS******
**********************/

    .button {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.button-log-in {
    color: #6EC78B;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #6EC78B;
}

.button-log-in:hover {
    color: #5CE68A;
    border: 1px solid #5CE68A;
}

.button-sign-up {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #6EC78B;
}

.button-sign-up:hover {
    background-color: #5CE68A;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an **invalid HTML**, as you cannot nest `<span>` directly inside `<ul>`. Only `<li>`s are allowed. You can add a class, say `right` to the `<li>` and `float` it.

```
<li class="right"><!-- Stuff --></li>
```

And give the following CSS:

```
.right {float: right;}
```

Make sure you give `overflow: hidden` to the parent `<ul>` to clear the `float`s.

Comment: @TomFinet Sure, lemme know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
#navbar ul li:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
}
```

it gives you second li element to the right side.

there is also lot many ways for doing this but this is the most shortest way.

Comment: This is *the most shortest*, I agree, but not the better way, because this is not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Most easy solution is to wrap the button groups in another div, eg. `<div class="nav-left"></div>` and `<div class="nav-right"></div>`. Then just add css attributes:

```
.nav-left { float: left; }
.nav-right { float: right; }
```

You might need to add a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix), depending on the rest of the styling.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution would be putting a div around the two elements that should be on the right, then float them right:

```
            <div class="right">
            <span class="padding"><a href="log_in.html" class="button button-log-in">Log In</a></span>
            <span class="padding"><a href="sign_up.html" class="button button-sign-up">Sign Up</a></span>
            </div>
```

css

```
 .right {
        float: right;
    }
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvo0ceu1/1/

Answer (score 1):

Go crazy and start using FLEXBOX capabilities. Minimal changes and it works like a charm.

AND move the buttons out of the UL, give them their own container div. Check the snippet for comments...

```css
* { outline: 1px dashed red } /* just for debugging, remove */

#navbar { /* ADD make navbar a flex container */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between; /* moves 2 elements (UL and #buttons)
                                       to either side of #navbar */
}

/*****NAVBAR****/
#navbar ul {
    display: flex;  /* ADD make UL a flex container too */
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* ADD grow child elements (LI, default = 0 1 auto)*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.5% 2%;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    color: #4F8E64;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/**********************
******NAV BUTTONS******
**********************/

    .button {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.button-log-in {
    color: #6EC78B;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #6EC78B;
}

.button-log-in:hover {
    color: #5CE68A;
    border: 1px solid #5CE68A;
}

.button-sign-up {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #6EC78B;
}

.button-sign-up:hover {
    background-color: #5CE68A;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <!--<li><a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="../img/PowerUpLogo.gif" class="logo"></a></li>-->
    <li><a href="home.html">Brand</a></li>
    <li><a href="stories.html">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="community.html">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="buttons"> <!-- id is optional -->
    <span class="padding"><a href="log_in.html"  class="button button-log-in">Log In</a></span>
    <span class="padding"><a href="sign_up.html" class="button button-sign-up">Sign Up</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```